# How to write this recursion with loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I saw the following as an exercise in a website. It basically says write the following function without using recursion and without using structures like vector, stack, etc:

```
void rec(int n) {
        if (n != 0) {
                cout << n << " ";
                rec(n-1);
                rec(n-1);
        }
}
```

At first I thought it was going to be easy, but I'm suprisingly struggling to accomplish it.

To understand it better, I defined it like a math function as the following:

f(x) = {1 if x = 0, f(x-1) + f(x-1) otherwise} (where + operator means concatenation and - is the normal minus)

However, Unrolling this made it harder, and I'm stuck. Is there any direct way to write it as a loop? And also, more generally, is there an algorithm to solve this type of problems?

Comment: Remember that recursion is just a way of leveraging the stack to do work for you. There's always an equivalent approach where you manage your own stack using a loop.

Comment: @tadman I know, I did a lot of those when I was studying back then, but I think there is a really simple approach for this and I can't see it. Usually unrolling the recursion worked for me always.

Comment: The problem is this branches down two paths, then those two branch as well. Maybe you could think about which output it gives, then find a pattern to those numbers and implement from that basis.

Comment: @tadman As I said, I unrolled the recursion and I see the pattern, but I don't see how to implement it easily with loops. I know there is definitely a way because recursions and iterations have the same "power" as you said.

Comment: @WilliamClements that's why I think this problem is interesting ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that while "*recursion and iteration have the same "power"*", recursion automatically allocates data (for example, its arguments and local variables), while iteration does not. Recursion uses the hardware stack (or *call stack*, if you may call it like that). When using iteration, you need to use a custom stack (in form of an actual data structure). To summarise, recursive calls and loops **do not** have the same "power". Recursion is superior in some aspects. I believe you would have to state that "recursion and iteration *backed up by data structures* have the same power".

Comment: How about this? [**Attempt on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c07bba759b8208f0) ;-) Is it beyond your constraints to recall the already done output? (I'm afraid so. Actually, it's the `std::ostringstream` which is "abused" as stack.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void loop(int n)
{
    int j = 0;
    int m = n - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < int(pow(2, n)) - 1; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        if (j == 0)
        {
            std::cout << n << " ";
            continue;
        }
        m = n - 1;
        while (true)
        {
            if (m == 1)
            {
                std::cout << m << " ";
                m = n - 1;
                break;
            }
            if (j >= int(pow(2, m)))
            {
                j = j - int(pow(2, m)) + 1;
            }
            if (j == 1)
            {
                std::cout << m << " ";
                m = n - 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                j--;
            }
            m--;
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

For n = 3 for instance

```
out =     [3 2 1 1 2 1 1] 
indexes = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Consider the list of indexes; for i > 0 and i <= 2^(m) the index i has the same value as the index i + 2^(m)-1 where m = n - 1. This is true for every n. If you are in the second half of the list, find its correspondent index in the first half by this formula. If the resulting number is 1, the value is m. If not, you are in a lower level of the tree. m = m - 1 and repeat until the index is 1 or m =1, in which case you've reached the end of the tree, print 1.

For instance, with n = 4, this is what happens with all the indexes, at every while step. p(x) means the value x gets printed at that index. A / means that index has already been printed.:

```
n = 4,m = 3
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
m = 3
[p(n=4) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
if(i >=2^3) -> i = i -2^3 + 1)
[/ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
if(i == 1) -> print m, else i = i -1
[/ p(3) 1 2 3 4 5 6 p(3)1 2 3 4 5 6]

m = 2
if (i >=2^2) -> i = i - 2^2 +1
[/ / 1 2 3 1 2 3 / 1 2 3 1 2 3] 
if(i == 1) -> print m, else i = i -1
[ / / p(2) 1 2 p(2) 1 2 / p(2) 1 2 p(2) 1 2]
m = 1
if (m == 1) -> print(m)
[ / / / p(1) p(1) / p(1) p(1) / / p(1) p(1) / p(1) p(1)]
```

Therefore the result is:

```
[4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1]
```

Comment: Interesting observation! This is also slightly more efficient than my idea (it seems to make less iterations but I think on a similar order of magnitude).

Comment: Thanks! I've added a small example because I fear it's hard to follow. I had some trouble getting the cases right

Answer (score 3):

If you fiddle with it enough, you can get at least one way that will output the ordered sequence without revisiting it :)

```js
let n = 5

// Recursive 
let rec_str = ''
function rec(n) { 
  if (n != 0) { 
    rec_str += n
    rec(n-1); 
    rec(n-1); 
  } 
}

rec(n)
console.log(rec_str)

// Iterative 
function f(n){
  let str = ''
  
  for (let i=1; i<1<<n; i++){
    let t = i
    let p = n
    let k = (1 << n) - 1

    while (k > 2){
      if (t < 2){
        break 
      } else if (t <= k){
        t = t - 1
        p = p - 1
        k = k >> 1
      } else {
        t = t - k
      }
    }
    str += p
  }
  console.log(str)
}

f(n)
```

(The code is building a string, which I think should be disallowed according to the rules, but only for demonstration; we could just output the number instead.)

Comment: The question is tagged as `c++`. This is, for sure, illegal `c++` syntax.

Comment: @Fureeish give me a break, this question is also tagged "recursion" and "algorithm" (albeit the latter was my edit :)

Comment: @Fureeish if you need help to convert this code to C++, please let me know. (To get the expected similar result, `str += p` would be a `cout` call.)

Comment: I believe I would be able to convert a basic JS code to C++ myself, thank you, but that's not the point. The question is tagged `c++` and I believe the answer should be in `c++`, regardless whether the topic touches any other, language-independent fields. If the language wouldn't have mattered, the question would not be tagged as language-specific, in my opinion.

Comment: @Fureeish I would agree if the code in C++ would require more significant language-specific calls and procedures. I like JS in this case because it's easy to add a clickable snippet. And for this particular routine, I thought the code is close enough to C to make that compromise.

Comment: @Fureeish considering that even the OP did not provide full working code, the conversion here to C++ is almost trivial.

Comment: I find the "*I like JS in this case because it's easy to add a clickable snippet*" to be absolutely of no value in such questions, but I see that the discussion is shifting away from the topic. Let's end it here.

Comment: @Fureeish so if I don't know C++, I should not be allowed to contribute an answer to this particular question? I think that would be the wrong approach. (So would be asking me to study enough of it to be able to write out my algorithm in that language.) In any case, there are *countless* helpful answers under the "algorithm" tag, that are also tagged C++ but do not provide C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

```
void via_loop(int n) {
  string prev = "1 ", ans = "1 ";
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    ans = to_string(i) + " " + prev + prev;
    prev = ans;
  }
  cout << ans;
}
```

Idea is to save result from the previous computation of each number. Full code:

```
void rec(int n) {
        if (n != 0) {
                cout << n << " ";
                rec(n-1);
                rec(n-1);
        }
}

void via_loop(int n) {
  string prev = "1 ", ans = "1 ";
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    ans = to_string(i) + " " + prev + prev;
    prev = ans;
  }
  cout << ans;
}

int main() {
  int n = 5;

  cout << "Rec : ";
  rec(n);
  cout << endl;

  cout << "Loop: ";
  via_loop(n);
  cout << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
Rec : 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1
Loop: 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 1 1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The example provided by the OP outputs a sequence in order. You cannot revisit the sequence. Building a string is a special structure, like a vector, which the OP said was disallowed.